# CollectionView section Header not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

When i initially added a sectionHeader to my collectionView it did appear as normal. I had this in my collectionViewController.swift and had a class for the header.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! HomeHeader

        return header
    }
```

Once I added this to `viewDidLoad()` the header no longer appears.

```
 let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 2
        let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 5
        let dimX = ((collectionView?.bounds.width)! - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross
        let dimY = CGFloat(dimX/187 * 125)
        let cellSize = CGSize(width: dimX , height: dimY)

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.itemSize = cellSize
        //layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
        collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
        collectionView?.reloadData()
```

I have this to force it to display two rows of cells on all screen sizes. (I'm still having an issue with that not resizing all the content in the cell though).

I'm not sure why the header no longer appears

(I'm using Swift 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need implement the header height method.

add`layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(100, 200)//size you want header in every section`

if you just want one header in special section, you can implement

`public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize` 
this method instead

what's more, I see you not register headerView.
I think you may also call this method `register(_ viewClass: AnyClass?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind elementKind: String, withReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` to register header